# WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library in clodera-quickstart-vm

Tags: hadoop, cloudera-quickstart-vm

Recently installed Cloudera-quickstart-vm, while running simple hadoop commands getting below error.

I tried to check path of libraries which it is complaining for but it does not exist.
Do I need to install /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native/libhadoop.so.1.0.0 ?If yes need help for install.

**Error:**
[image]

Comment: It's a warning, not an error. Your command still works fine

Comment: @cricket_007 That's correct for 1st command I got the result with warning but for 2nd command it did not return output